# How to replace a single quote in an Access 97 text field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to replace a `'` char in an MS Access column. Normally I would use something like the following to replace any text in a column

```
update SkechersPricat
set SketchersDivisionCode = left(SketchersDivisionCode,len(SketchersDivisionCode)-1
where right(SketchersDivisionCode,1) =' ' ';
```

but because my char is a `'` how do i get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this in Access 2010 and it seemed to do the trick for me:

```sql
update SkechersPricat
set SketchersDivisionCode = left(SketchersDivisionCode,len(SketchersDivisionCode)-1)
where right(SketchersDivisionCode,1) =''''
```

(Note that you were also missing a closing parenthesis `)` on the `left()` function.)

### Edit

The above query was also tested and confirmed working in Access 97

[image: a97.png]

Comment: this doesnet work in access 97 hence why i stated in access 97 it states the query is two complex?

Comment: @user3459421 Check your work. I just copied and pasted the above query into Access 97 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `ASC()` function for `ASCII` and test it with the `ASCII` value for single quote which is **39**, like:

```
UPDATE SkechersPricat
SET SketchersDivisionCode = left(SketchersDivisionCode,len(SketchersDivisionCode)-1)
WHERE ASC(right(SketchersDivisionCode,1)) = 39;
```

Comment: @Gord Thompsons version worked like a charm just had a syntax error in my statement

Comment: @user3459421: That's good that you have the solution for your problem. And it doesn't matter to me who gets the points as long as you are helped here which is what is SO is all about. GOD bless.